# Arbitrary input parameters to python functions

Tags: python, arguments, timedelta

I am currently working with the `timedelta` function in the `datetime` package. The default list of arguments for the `timedelta` is `datetime.timedelta(days=0, seconds=0, microseconds=0, milliseconds=0, minutes=0, hours=0, weeks=0)`.

I will be taking two inputs for my function: `frequency` and `timespan`, where `frequency` is an integer to specify in the designated timespan and the `timespan` is a string which is one of the days, seconds, microseconds, milliseconds, minutes, hours, weeks.

Currently I am writing a bunches of if-else to decide which parameters of the `timedelta` I should populate using the `frequency`. I am wondering if there is a more elegant way, e.g. parametrize the arguments for `timedelta`?

Thanks!

---Edit---
My current code:

```py
from datetime import datetime, timedelta

def myfunction(frequency, timespan):
   if timespan == "days":
      return datetime.now() + timedelta(days=frequency)
   elif timespan == "seconds":
      return datetime.now() + timedelta(seconds=frequency)
   elif timespan == "microseconds":
      return datetime.now() + timedelta(microseconds=frequency)
   elif timespan == "milliseconds":
      return datetime.now() + timedelta(milliseconds=frequency)
   elif timespan == "minutes":
      return datetime.now() + timedelta(minutes=frequency)
   elif timespan == "hours":
      return datetime.now() + timedelta(hours=frequency)
   else:
      return datetime.now() + timedelta(weeks=frequency)
```

Comment: Can you post your current code?

Comment: Did you mean: ‘timedelta(**{timespan:frequency})’?

Comment: Just posted my code

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can just put the parameters in a dict and let python do the work:

```py
def myfunction(frequency, timespan):
    return timedelta(**{timespan:frequency})
```